# Jquery Slide "To"

Tags: jquery

Alright,

I have a list of links off to the right where each link corresponds to their own div. The divs are "stacked" on top of each other. Basically I am having trouble trying to figure if I click on "link 4" how to make it slide down to div 4. And when you click on "link 1", how to get it to slide up to div 1. I guess I can't figure out how to make the div's slide up and down based on which link you click (if this can even be done).

HTML

```
<div id="slider"> 
    <div class="one"> </div> 
    <!--end slide-->  
    <div class="two"> </div> 
    <!--end slide-->  
    <div class="three"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->  
    <div class="four"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->  
</div>
<!-- end slider --> 
<div id="clicker"> 
    <a href="#" id="link-one">DLO</a>  
    <a href="#" id="link-two">test-a</a>  
    <a href="#" id="link-three">tes-a</a>  
    <a href="#" id="link-four">te-a</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML snippet?

Comment: thanks! I was just about to do that..

Comment: Does anyone else know what hes trying to do? I may have an idea, but im not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want the whole slider container to slide down? Or do you want to slide the page down to the links?

Comment: My first thought was something similar to an accordion menu.

Comment: I would like for users to lets say click on "link 4", and the slider slide down to "div 4", once on div 4, if a user clicked "link-2", the slider would slide up to "div 2"

Comment: Sounds to me like what rahul is saying and that its an accordion menu. Thats what im getting because you have div 4 inside the slider container. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ ??

Comment: O yeah.. I understand what you are suggesting. However, the "links" would be in a div floated off to the left, and the "slider" would be off to the right taking up the remaining space. So once a user clicks a link, the actual corresponding div (within) the slider slides either up/down into a centered view.

Comment: What do you mean by centered view?

Comment: For the div to become centered within your browser window. SO you would see "div 3" in the center, with "div 2" on top, and "div 4" below.. Basically a "go to and stop on the correct div". Thanks guys for your patience, as I know I am probably just being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should be looking into the append() function.  This code below works with jquery 1.4.3.  I added some inline styles just to make the divs stand out on my page.

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="one" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:gray;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="two" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:white;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="three" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:lime;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="four" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:silver;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
</div>
<!-- end slider -->
<div id="clicker">
    <a href="#" id="link-one" onclick="$('.one').append(this)">DLO</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-two" onclick="$('.two').append(this)">test-a</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-three" onclick="$('.three').append(this)">tes-a</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-four" onclick="$('.four').append(this)">te-a</a>
</div>
```

If you want to give it a cool little "fade in" effect you can hide the anchor text, then append it to the div, then fade it in.  Looks a little cooler.

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="one" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:gray;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="two" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:white;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="three" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:lime;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
    <div class="four" style="width:200px;height:20px;background-color:silver;"> </div>
    <!--end slide-->
</div>
<!-- end slider -->
<div id="clicker">
    <a href="#" id="link-one" onclick="$(this).hide();$('.one').append(this);$(this).fadeIn();">DLO</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-two" onclick="$(this).hide();$('.two').append(this);$(this).fadeIn();">test-a</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-three" onclick="$(this).hide();$('.three').append(this);$(this).fadeIn();">tes-a</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-four" onclick="$(this).hide();$('.four').append(this);$(this).fadeIn();">te-a</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the use of inline javascript?

Comment: after re-reading the question, I'm actually not sure this is what your asking for, it does actually sound more like an accordian or that type of thing.  my code above is more like move a link element into a different element on click.  Oh well, it's fun code anyway but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe I should just stick to the divs sliding left to right.. sort of like this: <a href="http://www2.furman.edu">Furman</a>  .. Anyone know how to achieve this slider effect (still using my links, without the number schema/hover they used/without the fade in/fade out)

Comment: I tried to look at the link that you posted but got a "403 FORBIDDEN" do you have any other example that I could see of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://www2.furman.edu/Pages/default.aspx    Something similar, but with the links off to the side so when a user clicks it slides the slide over to the corresponding slide...